# How do I get word frequency in a corpus using Scikit Learn CountVectorizer?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to compute a simple word frequency using scikit-learn's `CountVectorizer`.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

texts=["dog cat fish","dog cat cat","fish bird","bird"]
cv = CountVectorizer()
cv_fit=cv.fit_transform(texts)

print cv.vocabulary_
{u'bird': 0, u'cat': 1, u'dog': 2, u'fish': 3}
```

I was expecting it to return `{u'bird': 2, u'cat': 3, u'dog': 2, u'fish': 2}`.

Comment: [`CountVectorizer`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html) creates *"A mapping of terms to feature indices"* - if you just want the frequency, why not use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)?

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70721431/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

`cv.vocabulary_` in this instance is a dict, where the keys are the words (features) that you've found and the values are indices, which is why they're `0, 1, 2, 3`. It's just bad luck that it looked similar to your counts :)

You need to work with the `cv_fit` object to get the counts

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

texts = ["dog cat fish", "dog cat cat", "fish bird", "bird"]
cv = CountVectorizer()
cv_fit = cv.fit_transform(texts)

print(cv.get_feature_names())
print(cv_fit.toarray())
# ["bird", "cat", "dog", "fish"]
# [[0 1 1 1]
#  [0 2 1 0]
#  [1 0 0 1]
#  [1 0 0 0]]
```

Each row in the array is one of your original documents (strings), each column is a feature (word), and the element is the count for that particular word and document. You can see that if you sum each column you'll get the correct number

```
print(cv_fit.toarray().sum(axis=0))
# [2 3 2 2]
```

Honestly though, I'd suggest using `collections.Counter` or something from NLTK, unless you have some specific reason to use scikit-learn, as it'll be simpler.

Comment: Probably we don't need `toarray()` whereas its space complexity is high for large number of tokens. Only `print(cv_fit.sum(axis=0))` works fine. Use `list(np.array(cv_fit.sum(axis=0))[0])` to match the data structure.

Answer (score 27):

`cv_fit.toarray().sum(axis=0)` definitely gives the correct result, but it will be much faster to perform the sum on the sparse matrix and then transform it to an array:

```
np.asarray(cv_fit.sum(axis=0))
```

Answer (score 24):

We are going to use the zip method to make dict from a list of words and list of their counts

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np    
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

texts=["dog cat fish", "dog cat cat", "fish bird", "bird"]    

cv = CountVectorizer()   
cv_fit = cv.fit_transform(texts)    
word_list = cv.get_feature_names() 
count_list = cv_fit.toarray().sum(axis=0)
```

The outputs are following:

```
>> print word_list
['bird', 'cat', 'dog', 'fish']    
>> print count_list
[2 3 2 2]    
>> print dict(zip(word_list,count_list))
{'fish': 2, 'dog': 2, 'bird': 2, 'cat': 3}
```

Comment: `cv_fit.toarray().sum(axis=0)` makes the RAM explodes as it requires to densify the sparse matrix. Look at @pieterbons answer for a better approach.

Answer (score 5):

Combining every ones else's views and some of my own :)
Here is what I have for you

```
from collections import Counter
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize

text='''Note that if you use RegexpTokenizer option, you lose 
natural language features special to word_tokenize 
like splitting apart contractions. You can naively 
split on the regex \w+ without any need for the NLTK.
'''

# tokenize
raw = ' '.join(word_tokenize(text.lower()))

tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'[A-Za-z]{2,}')
words = tokenizer.tokenize(raw)

# remove stopwords
stop_words = set(stopwords.words('english'))
words = [word for word in words if word not in stop_words]

# count word frequency, sort and return just 20
counter = Counter()
counter.update(words)
most_common = counter.most_common(20)
most_common
```

#Output
(All ones)

```
[('note', 1),
 ('use', 1),
 ('regexptokenizer', 1),
 ('option', 1),
 ('lose', 1),
 ('natural', 1),
 ('language', 1),
 ('features', 1),
 ('special', 1),
 ('word', 1),
 ('tokenize', 1),
 ('like', 1),
 ('splitting', 1),
 ('apart', 1),
 ('contractions', 1),
 ('naively', 1),
 ('split', 1),
 ('regex', 1),
 ('without', 1),
 ('need', 1)]
```

One can do better than this in terms of efficiency but if you are not worried about it too much, this code is the best.

Comment: Old version of the code threw the following import error: "NameError: name 'word_tokenize' is not defined", just added the import to line 4. Good job, nice solution @Pradeep-Singh.

Answer (score 3):

Combining the answers by @YASH-GUPTA for readable results and by @pieterbons for RAM efficiency, but needed to make an adjustment and add a couple of parentheses.
Working code:

```
import numpy as np    
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

texts = ["dog cat fish", "dog cat cat", "fish bird", "bird"]    

cv = CountVectorizer()   
cv_fit = cv.fit_transform(texts)    
word_list = cv.get_feature_names()

# Added [0] here to get a 1d-array for iteration by the zip function. 
count_list = np.asarray(cv_fit.sum(axis=0))[0]

print(dict(zip(word_list, count_list)))
# Output: {'bird': 2, 'cat': 3, 'dog': 2, 'fish': 2}
```