# Converting sklearn CountVectorizer matrix to list of dictionaries

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I have created a matrix using `CountVectorizer` which looks like

```
[[1, 2, 1....],
 [0, 4, 0,...],
 [0, 0, 7....]]
```

where each column maps to a feature name

```
['sweet', 'pretty', 'bad'....]
```

**What I want to do** 
To convert the rows of matrix to a list of dictionaries of the form

```
[{'sweet': 1, 'pretty': 2, 'bad': 1  ..} , {'sweet': 0, 'pretty': 4, 'bad': 0  ..} , {'sweet': 0, 'pretty': 0, 'bad': 7  ..}]
```

which is basically doing what `inverse_transform` function of `DictVectorizer` would do but since I have not created the matrix from the dictionary I don't think I can use that because I get this error

> 'DictVectorizer' object has no attribute 'feature_names_'

How do I achieve this? Does NumPy provide a built in function to convert the array into a list of dictionaries where I could map each column to a given key?

Comment: would help to provide some sample `data`

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/56712583/34935.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is get_feature_names
not sure if there is a builtin way to achieve what you want but it's esily achievable with a simple map

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer() 

#`data` is an array of strings

tdata = cv.fit_transform(data) 

ft = cv.get_feature_names() 

#create a dictionary with feature names as keys and row elements as values

result = list(map(lambda row:dict(zip(ft,row)),tdata.toarray()))
```

Edit: memory saving solution

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.SparseDataFrame(tdata, columns=ft)
```

Comment: The last line was what I was looking for thanks. However I'm working on a text file with over million lines so it gives me a memory error with this. I think it might be efficient if I could convert the array to pandas DataFrame, it does have an inbuilt method to do this but I'm getting " DataFrame constructor not properly called!" when I do DataFrame(data = X, columns= ft)

Comment: you could use something like `df =pd.DataFrame(tdata.toarray(),columns=ft)`

Comment: or even better, a sparse dataframe `df = pd.SparseDataFrame(tdata,columns=ft)`

Comment: Didn't work for me, but this did: `pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(tdata, columns=ft)`