# How to add a word_count column to a dataFrame using scikit-learn?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, countvectorizer

I am trying to build a sentiment analysis on amazon data. So, I started by reading the data

`data = pd.read_csv("amazon_baby.csv")`

```
---name---|------review-----|----rating----|
__________|_________________|______________|
          |                 |              |
          |                 |              |
          |                 |              |
___________________________________________|
```

I want to add another column that contains the word count vector for each review to be like this

```
---name---|------review-----|----rating----|----word_count----|
__________|_________________|______________|__________________|
          |                 |              |                  |
          |                 |              |                  |
          |                 |              |                  |
______________________________________________________________|
```

I use the following code

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
data['word_count'] = vectorizer.fit_transform(data['review'])
data.head()
```

While I expect to see cells contain an output like this:

```
[{'recommend': 1.0, 'disappointed': 1.0, 'wise': 1.0, 'love': 1.0, 'it': 3.0, 'planet': 1.0, 'and': 3.0, 'bags': 1.0, 'wipes': 1.0, 'highly': 1.0, 'not': 2.0, 'early': 1.0, 'came': 1.0, 'i': 1.0, 'does': 1.0, 'my': 2.0, 'was': 1.0, 'now': 1.0, 'wipe': 1.0, 'holder': 1.0, 'leak': 1.0, 'keps': 1.0, 'osocozy': 1.0, 'moist': 1.0}]
```

Instead I have the following output:

```
(0, 60077)\t1\n  (0, 24510)\t1\n  (0, 66612)...
```

Comment: I think this should answer your question [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488446/how-do-i-get-word-frequency-in-a-corpus-using-scikit-learn-countvectorizer)

Comment: I want to but the result of every review in the new column. How should I do this operation on every row?