# How do I get word/term frequencies in a corpus using Scikit Learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a corpus of documents and I'd like to extract the word frequencies in each document.  I could use `CountVectorizer()` to get term counts per document, and I could use `TfidfVectorizer()` to get term frequency-inverse document frequency, but neither seems to give me term frequencies alone. How do I get term frequencies?

This [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488446/how-do-i-get-word-frequency-in-a-corpus-using-scikit-learn-countvectorizer) seems to ask my question, but the question and answers there concern term counts, not term frequencies. Maybe I'm the one misunderstanding these terms, but my understanding is that term counts are the integer number of times each term appears in the document whereas term frequencies are the term counts divided by the document length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is the [`TfidfTransformer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfTransformer.html) for this purpose. From the docs:

> Transform a count matrix to a normalized **tf** *or* **tf-idf** representation

Since it only transforms a count matrix, you would need to use it in conjunction with an already vectorized matrix or use `CountVectorizer` before:

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer, TfidfTransformer


X_count = CountVectorizer().fit_transform(X_train)  # use first if X_train is not vectorized
X_tf = TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False).fit_transform(X_count)
```

Note that by setting `use_idf=False` you will get the term-frequency only.

Comment: Is this the same as setting `use_idf=False` in `TfidfVectorizer()`?

Comment: @RylanSchaeffer yes, it is the same.